# Socket Programming over WLAN

Tags: python, android, sockets, network-programming, router

I am trying to create an android app which connects to a socket created on the desktop. I did a lot of testing and figured out that my routing was giving me a hard time.

When I tried to connect over a mobile hotspot, it was working perfectly fine. But when I connected over the router, my connection was getting rejected or something. I tried connecting both ways, one with my android as serversocket and one with my desktop as server socket.

I think the issue is because of port forwarding or something, but since I'm new to networking, I don't know how to configure it.

I looked up online and tried some stuff myself, however nothing worked.
This is how my D-Link router port forwarding setup is.

[D-Link router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJfrP.png)

I have a socket running at port 8080 hosted by my android device with ip 192.168.0.122 and my laptop is at ip 192.168.0.123

This is client code which i have on my laptop(client.py)

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = input("IP: ")
port = int(input("Port: "))
s.connect((ip,port))

print(s)

s.send(bytes(str("Hello!"), "utf-8"))
```

I am using python(spyder) to connect as client by enterring the socket ip address and the port number.

The main problem I am facing is the weird behaviour of it working sometimes and then after like a few hours, it just stops working without doing anything. Then I try the same method I did last time to make it work, but it still doesn't work. I feel like my router is moody and only works when it wants to, and that is the weird behaviour.

Comment: In the image, there is nothing configured. What exactly did you try and did not work?

Comment: As long as you use local ips like 192.168.... you dont have to forward anything.

Comment: Switch of the firewall of your pc. And dont bind your server to an ip address.

Comment: `When I tried to connect over a mobile hotspot, it was working perfectly fine.` That setup is unclear. Hiw exactly?

Comment: @AyushJain In a D-link router, Virtual Server and Port Forwarding are usually separate but similar features. In either case, simply make sure the desktop PC has static IP `192.168.0.100` assigned to it (either in the OS, or via the router's DHCP server), then bind a server socket on it to either `0.0.0.0:8080` or `192.168.0.100:8080`, then set a VS/PF rule in the router for `IP 192.168.0.100, External/Public Port 8080, Internal/Private Port 8080`.  Now the Android client should be able to connect to the router's WAN IP on port 8080, and the connection will be forwarded to the desktop server.

Comment: @blackapps I tried turning off the McCafe Firewall(Windows was already off due to McCafe). I used DHCP to set my Laptop's ip to 192.168.0.121 and  my android device's to 192.168.0.122. I then created a socket on my android and tried to connect via laptop. Didn't work.

[link](https://imgur.com/IpceBB9)

This is how i configured my router settings.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried your way as well, with pyhton on laptop creating a socket and then trying to connect via android. The firewall was off.

The thing is I was trying the same thing with a different laptop(MacOS) and somehow it worked. But when I tried the exact same after a few hours, it did not, even after restarting the router.

Comment: @blackapps I have a samsung a71 phone which i used to create a portable wifi network. When i connected both devices with it and tried. It was working flawlessly. I think my router is the problem, but I wanted to confirm the same.

Comment: @AyushJain that screenshot does not match your description. The Server IP needs to be the LAN IP that the server socket is bound to. You said the PC's LAN IP is 192.168.0.121, but that screenshot shows the forwarding is to 192.168.0.122 instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The server socket is set up on Android which has 192.168.0.122. The Server IP Address section should contain this ip right?

Comment: @AyushJain if the client and server sockets are both on the same LAN side, or the server socket is on the WAN side, you don't need to forward anything. Forwarding only applies from WAN-to-LAN, not LAN-to-WAN or LAN-to-LAN.

Comment: @RemyLebeau then what do you think might be the reason for this weird behaviour?

Comment: @AyushJain I’m getting lost in the details you have provided so far. Please [edit] your question to show the actual code in both client and server, and be VERY clear about which device is running which code, and which IP is assigned to which device, and which device is on the LAN and WAN side of the router, and which IP the client is trying to connect to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay, I am sorry about the confusing problem. I have edited the question. The server is running on android and I dont have the code for it now, but it is a simple java program creating a ServerSocket at port 8080.

Comment: @AyushJain which side of the router does the Android device reside - on the LAN side or the WAN side? If LAN, there should be no problem with the desktop PC connecting to it. But if WAN, you have to connect to the device’s public Internet IP, and if the Android device gets its Internet connection from a cellular network then making inbound connections to it is going to be near impossible, as cellular providers tend to prevent customers from running servers on their networks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I do not know how to find out if it is on LAN or WAN. Both are connected wirelessly to the same router.

Comment: @AyushJain if the Android device is connected to the router by Ethernet or WiFi, then it is on the LAN side (same with the desktop PC). Otherwise, it is on the WAN side.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Then it is on WAN. I even tried by turning on airplane mode then just turning on the WiFi and still no result.